# NotNullValidator error message inconsistency

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I'm using NotNullValidator from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators NotNullValidator.

And i'm using custom error message declared in

```
[NotNullValidator(Tag = "error", ErrorMessage = "Hodnota musí být vyplněna")]
```

On my machine, this works great, but on a tester's machine instead of my custom error message, it shows "The value cannot be null"

Tester's computer is using windows in the same language as I do. Any idea why is this happening? 
Thank you.

Comment: could it be an outdated version?

Comment: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation version 5.1.508

Comment: i mean with your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. That the tester is testing on different version than me?

Comment: possibly. i'm not sure how you are deploying it. could be cached somewhere too.

Comment: 100% same version. The caching is a possibility, but i don't see how that would be possible